# how to get phone number using google api

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, google-maps

this is my code

```
function show(placelanlat,names) 
{   
var placenames=names;
var planlat=placelanlat;
var newStr= planlat.replace(/[(\)]/g,'');
var aCars = newStr.split(',');
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(12.588,-83.667);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvass"), myOptions);
var input = newStr;
var latlngStr = input.split(",",2);
var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {  
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  if (results[1]) {
    map.setZoom(11);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      map: map,
      icon: 'images/images.png'
    });
    infowindow.setContent(placenames+"</br>"+results[0].formatted_address+"</br>");
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
    }
  else {
  alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
  }
   });
 return false; // MANDATORY!
  }
```

if i set

```
infowindow.setContent(placenames+"</br>"
                      +results[0].formatted_address
                      +"</br>"+results[0].formatted_phone);
results[0].formatted_phone ->
```

this is showing empty.why?
where i want to change to get place phone number.
example:http://www.google.com/maps?source=uds&daddr=India,++%28India%29+@20.593684,78.96288&saddr=37.781287,-122.395575

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you use [`The Google Places API (Experimental)`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/)
then follow these steps

- first get an **API key**
- now use **Place Search Requests**

  A Place Search request is an HTTP URL of the following form:

  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/output?parameters

Certain parameters are required to initiate a Place Search request

```
key (required) — Your application's API key. 
location (required) —  This must be specified as latitude,longitude.
radius (required) — The distance (in meters) within which to return Place results.
sensor (required) — This value must be either true or false.
```

Each result within the results array may contain

> **reference** contains a unique token that you can use to retrieve additional information about this place in a Place Details request.
>   You can store this token and use it at any time in future to refresh
>   cached data about this Place, but the same token is not guaranteed to
>   be returned for any given Place across different searches.

- Once you have a `reference` from a **Place Search request**, you can request more details about a particular establishment or point of interest by initiating a **Place Details request**.

  A Place Details request returns more comprehensive information about the indicated place such as its complete address, phone number, user rating, etc.
  A Place Details request is an HTTP URL of the following form:

  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/output?parameters

Certain parameters are required to initiate a search request.

```
key (required) — Your application's API key.
reference (required) — A textual identifier that uniquely identifies a place, returned from a Place search request.
sensor (required) —  This value must be either true or false.
```

- output of  Place Details contains

  `formatted_phone_number` and  `international_phone_number`.

Hope it would helps u.

Comment: you see this link.                                                                  http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

Comment: I have updated my answer. Note: you must need `API key` for that

Comment: ya.i have place name and lan &lat of place name and API key

Comment: ya.i have place name and lan &lat of place name and API key. var placenames=names;
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
API key= my api key.    how to put into my above code.

Comment: i have used:<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>

Comment: @SANR1103219 : try with given lat long (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-83.667,12.588&radius=500&sensor=true&key=your_api_key) but it returns `ZERO_RESULTS` means that the search was successful but returned no results. This may occur if the search was passed a latlng in a remote location.

Comment: you see my code:http://jsfiddle.net/sankars/qNmpm/1/                                                               from this code how get phone number.this is correct or not.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6377/discussion-between-sanr1103219-and-diecho)

Comment: @Appu Hami, do not use such language here. You might get banned from SO.